# Yii2 before submit form with render fails but works with renderajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, yii2

I have a form when i call beforesubmit when using render in my controller the form proceeds without ajax submission using the default submission but works when in a modal form with renderAjax

The is the controller code:

```
public function actionProfile()
{
 if(\Yii::$app->request->post()){

   //perform acctions
}else{
       return $this->render('profile',["user" =>$user]); //this works when its renderAjax
    }
```

In the from

```
div class="panel-body">
     <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([ 'id' => "userform",]); ?>
       // form fields

       <?= Html::submitButton('Update Profile')  ?>  //its an update
     <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Now the js script on the form view

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS

   $('form#userform').on('beforeSubmit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault() //tried adding this but also fails
    // do stuff here

     return false;
  })

 JS;
 $this->registerJs($script,   \yii\web\View::POS_LOAD);  //thus its on document.ready
```

?>

This form submits just like a normal form would do without being done via ajax

I cannot use render Ajax anymore since the design of the app changed from modals to flat designs but i need to submit via ajax to trigger a notification and also prevent page refreshes.

Comment: 1) Did you check if  beforeSubmit event is being triggerred ? Log something inside it ??

Comment: I have tried with an alert but its never triggered thats whats really confusing the reason why its never triggered

Comment: Ive tried also wrappig the code inside a document.ready and even moving it  to POS_HEAD, but also fails